# Ambiguous match found exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5, .net-core-3.1

Well this one used to work great, before upgrading to `.NET 5` from `net core 3.1`

The extension method that produces the error is

```
public static IQueryable Set(this myContext context, Type T)
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(myContext).GetMethod(nameof(myContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(T);

    return method.Invoke(context, null) as IQueryable;
}
```

and especially this line

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(myContext).GetMethod(nameof(myContext.Set), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

the stack trace is

```
   at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImplCommon(String name, Int32 genericParameterCount, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
   at System.Type.GetMethod(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
   at Extensions.QueryableExtensions.Set(RetailContext context, Type T, Boolean dummy) in QueryableExtensions.cs:line 36
```

Where this Ambiguous error comes from?

Comment: Not enough, ahem, context. E.g. what is `myContext.Set` (how is it declared)?

Comment: Pls share enough code and your stack trace is also not entire.

Comment: Doesn't answer you question but you should migrate to net6 as net5 is already EOL https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: Sounds like there is more than one method with that name. Is `Set` overloaded?

Answer (score 1):

There are two overloads for the DbContext.Set method. You need to tell reflection which one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-5.0.0

E.g.

```cs
MethodInfo method = typeof(myContext).GetMethod(nameof(myContext.Set), Array.Empty<Type>());
```

```cs
MethodInfo method = typeof(myContext).GetMethod(nameof(myContext.Set), new Type[] { typeof(string) });
```

I removed the `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance` parameter as this is the default. If you were looking for a non public method you could use one of the overloads that includes it but I believe they require some other parameters as well.

A third options is to use the GetMethods call and then use linq to pick the correct one.

E.g.

```cs
typeof(myContext).GetMethods(/*Can add binding flags if needed*/).First(w => w.Name == nameof(myContext.Set) && w.GetParameters().Count() == 0 /* Or some other condition to disambiguate the function*/)
```